# array loop not working correctly? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

Trying to count how many elements within the array are not equal to 0, is something set up wrong?

I'd like to check all values in the array (it's a sudoku board) and then when all elements are "full" I need to return true.
Is something off?

```
bool boardFull(const Square board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE])
{
    int totalCount=0;
    for (int index1 = 0; index1 < BOARD_SIZE; index1++)
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < BOARD_SIZE; index2++){ 
             if(board[index1][index2].number!=0)
                totalCount++;
        }
    if(totalCount=81)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```

Comment: I tempt to copy my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563553/tell-the-program-what-to-do-when-no-save-data-is-found-nsuserdefaults-iphone/2563576#2563576  here.

Comment: Why using constants for dimension and hardcoded `81` value ? isn't it meant to be `BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE` ? You've got a magic value here :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have = rather than ==

```
if (totalCount == 81)
```

is the correct line.

Doing this with a single "=" actually assigns the value 81 to totalCount, so your test is essentialy:

```
if (81)
```

And since in C++ anything nonzero is true, this is always true

Comment: I've been staring at this for too long. Thanks, now I feel stupid.

Comment: get into the habit of compiling with high levels of warnings turned on - the compiler would have spotted this for you

Comment: Or write it like this:  if( 81 == totalCount )  then it doesnt matter what warning level you are on.

Comment: @John: Until you have `if (var_a = var_b)` where only warnings can save you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `=` that should be a `==`.  That's all I'll say, since it's homework.

Also, why do you have a constant for `BOARD_SIZE`, then check against `81` at the end?  Wouldn't checking against `BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE` be better?

Comment: I guess that works as well, but in this case BOARD_SIZE does not change (declared as const elsewhere) so it's okay (albeit bad programming?)

Comment: @igor, sure, but if it doesn't change why don't you have 9 everywhere, that's less typing than `BOARD_SIZE` if you don't care about it being a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Is the If(totalCount=81) a typo in this post or your code?  Looks like you've assigned the value there.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the function as soon as you find the first 0, and it's possible to solve this with a single loop:

```
bool boardFull(const Square board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE])
{
    const Square* p = board[0];
    for (int n = BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE; n; --n, ++p)
    {
        if (p->number == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I prefer algorithms to hand-written loops:

```
struct Square
{
    int number;

    bool is_zero() const
    {
        return number == 0;
    }
};

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

bool boardFull(const Square board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE])
{
    return std::find_if(
        board[0],
        board[BOARD_SIZE],
        std::mem_fun_ref(&Square::is_zero)
    )== board[BOARD_SIZE];
}
```